# Installation Source List

Tags: repository, software-sources, gnupg

I want to add to the `sources.list` file for the installation media to give it extra repositories that I normally utilize. How do I do that? Additionally, how would I save any GPG keys that go along with this kind of repositories?

I have built up an install disk starting with the basic server iso and whenever I go to install the thing I always end up having to reinput the `sources.list` and GPG keys. Which is very annoying.